# What are the development tools on the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, development

Are there any development tools like NetBeans or Eclipse on OS X that I can use to write an application?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. Can someone fix the spelling in the title?

Comment: You mention Netbeans and Eclipse - are you specifically looking for Java-related tools, or development in general? There are dozens of development tools/platforms you can use on the Mac (many of which I'm happy to mention if you are casting your net wider than Java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) was good for your job. If you want use NetBeans and Eclipse on your Mac, you can download them, too, because they have OS X distributions.

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html)

Comment: It is Xcode, not XCode, xCode, or X Code (my friends on the Xcode team point that out constantly ;-)

Comment: I edited I write it like other apple apps.

Comment: You should also correct the overall syntax and orthography.

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for Java development on the Mac, both NetBeans and Eclipse have a distribution for Mac OS X. Xcode also has support for Java, but it is not a Java-centric tool.

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in vim and emacs. Both of them [can be used **as IDE**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE).

Built-in vim and emacs don't have GUI (only console versions) but at least they are relatively new in latest OSX versions.

If you want GUI versions there are [**MacVim**](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and a couple of [GUI **emacs***es*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS) for OSX.